# [Database Design]:How to share resources among accounts?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

Using google doc, I am able to share my documents with others. I wonder how they implement it underlying in terms of DB design?

The simplest way I imagine is to use a joining table which keeps a many-to-many relationship between resource and accounts to share.

However, I wonder if there is any well-known pattern for this? If the account has hundred resources, then hundred joining tables seem not a scale way, as for each resource you have to write specific code. Is there any thing like RBAC(role based access control) for this sharing problem?

thank you

Comment: asking this question to http://dba.stackexchange.com/ will improve your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: @Ismet, thanks, having done it